# Not able to bind to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have written a simple ASP.NET WEBApi which returns the list of customer and I am trying to bind to the UI.

Find below my WEB Api Controller:

```
    public class DummyController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.FirstName = "John";
            customer.LastName = "Doe";
            customers.Add(customer);
            customer = new Customer();
            customer.FirstName = "Mike";
            customer.LastName = "Doobey";
            customers.Add(customer);

            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customers);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Angular Controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dummyCtrl($scope) {
        $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:81/Api/dummy", function (resp) {
            $scope.dummy = resp;
            $scope.json = angular.toJson(resp);
            console.log($scope.json);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Executing the Angular Controller:

```
<body ng-controller="dummyCtrl">
    <div>
        <ul>
    <li ng-repeat = "person in dummy">
        <span>{{person.FirstName}}</span>
        <span>{{person.lastname}}</span>
    </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am able to see the JSON data in Chrome Dev Tools but not able to see the output in browser.

```
[{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"},{"FirstName":"Mike","LastName":"Doobey"}] :81/:24
[{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"},{"FirstName":"Mike","LastName":"Doobey"}] :81/:24
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you may want to investigate into `scope.$apply()`.

Comment: if you want to use $.getJson then you need to wrap the code inside $scope.$apply(fn)

Comment: you should accept his answer id you are happy with it.

Answer (score 4):

You should use angularJS' own Wrapper around XmlHTTPRequest which does a $digest automatically. So change your code to this:

```
function dummyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:81/Api/dummy").then( function (resp) {
        $scope.dummy = resp.data;
        $scope.json = angular.toJson(resp.data);
        console.log($scope.json);
    });
}
```

See here for more information: [Angular $http reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#get)

Comment: Alternatively, if for some reason you *have* to use jQuery's XHR  or some other such tool... you can use $scope.$apply() in your success function to update angular. ... but stick with $http if you can.